# Runing MongoDB queries on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I like MongoDB, I like MySQL What to choose? BOTH

---

I want to use MySQL for data storing and queries, but sometimes to use MongoDB syntax for easily find a row I need.

Most of the column in my table contain primative values (dates,string,etc') one of the column (`headers`) contain stringify JSON data, I want to query

```
| time     | headers                                        |
| 00:00:00 | {"content-type":"text","accept-language":"en"} |
| 00:00:00 | {"content-type":"text","accept-language":"en"} |
| 00:00:00 | {"content-type":"text","accept-language":"sp"} |
| 00:00:00 | {"content-type":"text","accept-language":"sp"} |
```

I have this query in **`mongodb`**

```
db.findAll({'accept-language':'en'})
```

I want it to work in **`mysql`**
I can do something like that:

```
mysql.open('select * from mytable',function(err,rows){
    rows.filter(function(i){
        return JSON.parse(rows(i).headers)['accept-language']=='en'
    })
})
```

I'm searching for a simple way to convert every MongoDB findAll query to MySQL. In this situation I can simply do

```
select * from mytable where headers like '%en%'
```

But I'm searching for more generic way.

Comment: If you upgrade to MySQL 5.7.8, you'll find that it has JSON support built-in (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: I have `5.6` and it unupgradable for me

Comment: This is basically asking for recommendations for tools, and is therefore "off-topic" for this site. I'm sure a little searching should reveal that there are products that handle this, being either mongodb syntax to SQL or SQL syntax to MongoDB. I personally think there is a real impedance mismatch between the two, especially in either case if storage is optimally designed for one or the other. So such tools would never "truly" be optimal for either engine.